# API Calls Generating Notifications Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a weather app with java in Android Studio.
I am looking to be able to notify a user when there is a weather update.
How would I do this if I am calling an API to retrieve current weather data?
Would I continuously make API calls in the background, and notify the user if there is a change?
It seems that this method would be wildly inefficient and there must be a more efficient way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is push messaging.  Push messaging allows a server to send a notification directly to a device.  Preferably, whatever API you use has a websocket or FCM notification API.  If so, use it.  If not, you're going to need to proxy it through your own server-  have your own server query the API every so often (whatever frequency you think is right) and if there's a change you push a notification to the appropriate devices.

Please note every server API has its own rules and terms of service.  Some may expressly disallow you proxying like I said, or may only allow X requests per minute, or may require you to pay per request.  The burden of investigating and following those rules is on you.